# Modify Hadoop NameNode web interface

Tags: linux, hadoop, hadoop-plugins

Is there a proper and/or minimally intrusive way to extend the NameNode web interface of Hadoop (I am using version 2.8.5), for example, by adding a new tab with a view of the cluster in a different way/a way that is specifically tailored to my project? A Hadoop plugin I haven't stumbled upon maybe?

Comment: You could find/edit the HTML directly on the nodes. Plugins don't really make sense for HTML

Comment: @OneCricketeer would this require rebuilding the hadoop source and/or restarting the cluster?

Comment: Not that I know of. I think the namenode UI is just angular code